# Practical Malware Analysis - Lab 5.1 Question 11 function sub_100036C3

Tags: winapi, assembly, disassembly, malware, ida

Just wanted to ask one question about sub_100036C3, because I did not get the detailed answer that was given in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272901).

Brief intro:

Page 107. Question 11. What does the export PSLIST do?

Page 498. Answer: The sub_100036C3 function checks to see if
the OS version is Windows Vista/7 or XP/2003/2000.

Disassembled code:

[image: disassembled code]

We see instruction:

```
cmp [ebp+VersionInformation.dwMajorVersion], 5
jb short loc_100036FA
```

`dwMajorVersion` is 5 for XP/2003/2000.

`dwMajorVersion` is 6 for Windows Vista/7.

But in disassembled code instruction `jb short loc_100036FA` will not jump to loc_100036FA only if dwMajorversion is >= 5 and will jump only if dwMajorVersion < 5 (jump if below).

So in my opinion it could not be used to choose between XP and  Vista/7, because 5 and 6 all fall in red arrow.

Please, can someone explain, am I right or what mistake did I do?

Comment: The phrase, "checks to see if the OS version is Windows Vista/7 or XP/2003/2000" is open to grammatical ambiguity and misinterpretation. As in, "Is it black or blue?" - with a perfectly acceptable answer being, "yes". So if, `dwMajorVersion` is less than 5, it is **NOT** 2000/2003/XP *or* Vista/Win7. If it is >= 5, it could be.

Comment: ... So, the test could be to see if the OS is earlier than 2000.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, I agree about grammatical ambiguity. May be it is the case here. Thank you very much for spotting it. Just wanted to know if I didn't make mistake and logic is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function sub_100036C3 just makes a judgment to determine whether the host operating system is Win2000 or above(This may be why it returns a bool value instead of three options (Windows Vista/7? Or XP/2003/2000? Or neither?)).

If we use disassembly, the logic of this function is roughly as follows：

```
BOOL sub_100036C3()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOA VersionInformation;
    VersionInformation.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXA);
    GetVersionExA(&VersionInformation);

    return VersionInformation.dwPlatformId == 2 && VersionInformation.dwMajorVersion >= 5;
}
```

So as long as the version is not Windows 95, they will follow the middle process.
[image]